# Como acompanhar a execução de arquivo php pelo console?

Tags: php, include

> Update do update: na verdade meu problema não tinha nada a ver com este trecho do `blockquote` aí debaixo. Aprendi a depurar o PHP, e encontrei vários erros, mas nem vou entrar aqui em cada um deles porque não vem ao caso... Então mesmo tendo resolvido de outro jeito, os comentários e a resposta do Guilherme me ajudaram a entender alguns conceitos, e como acho que pode ajudar outros usuários, decidi não remover a pergunta e aceitar a resposta.

-.-

> Update: Encontrei o problema, que está neste trecho:

```
 <blockquote>
        <strong> <em>RECURSO DE REVISTA. [...] RESCISÃO DO CONTRATO DE TRABALHO - NULIDADE - AUSÊNCIA DE ASSISTÊNCIA SINDICAL.
        O objetivo da assistência sindical no pedido de demissão decorre da consagração do princípio da
        irrenunciabilidade dos direitos trabalhistas. Retrata o art. 477, § 1º, da CLT, norma cogente, que condiciona
        o pedido de demissão e a quitação do contrato de trabalho firmado pelo empregado cuja relação jurídica vigorou
        por mais de um ano, à assistência perante o Sindicato. Nesse sentido, a formalidade determinada pela norma, se
        não cumprida, torna nulo o ato. Incumbe ao empregador o cumprimento da formalidade prevista no art. 477, § 1º,
        da CLT, sob pena de não se convalidar o pedido de demissão, quando não houver a homologação, nos
        termos previstos na norma. Precedentes. Recurso de revista conhecido e provido. [...]</em></strong> (TST   PROCESSO Nº
        TST-RR-256-42.2010.5.02.0088, 6ª Turma, Relatora Desembargadora Convocada CILENE FERREIRA AMARO SANTOS,
        Data de Julgamento: 10/12/2014 - grifos nossos)
    </blockquote>
```

E o problema parece ser dentro do texto mesmo, achei que fosse a utilização de colchetes, mas acho que nem é, tentei escapar com `\` e não funcionou.

Na verdade, esta outra parte também está dando o mesmo problema (já testei só uma parte, sem a outra, e dá o mesmo problema):

```
<p>
            <?php echo $motivdesligjust; ?>
            <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $motivdesligind; ?>
            </p>
```

Não posso chamar as variáveis dentro das tags `<p></p>`?

**/update**

Estou com um problema aqui na execução de um arquivo php, que usa `include` pra incluir outros arquivos, e não consigo descobrir a causa. Parece ser um loop infinito, mas não estou usando `for`, `while`, nada, só chamo as variáveis escapando o html, e uso um `if` ou outro...

O arquivo fica rodando no navegador e não para mais, fica a mensagem "Aguardando localhost", e depois disso nenhum outro arquivo php consegue rodar antes de eu resetar o phpstorm.

Então queria saber se tem algum comando pra eu acompanhar a execução, e saber porque ele fica rodando nesse loop infinito.

É um erro estranho, porque são vários arquivos incluídos por `include`, e se retiro os primeiros 3 por exemplo, ele funciona, e o mesmo ocorre se eu deixo só os três primeiros, mas já revirei os arquivos e não encontro o problema.

Comment: Ao invés de `include` tente `include_once` e veja se resolve

Comment: Já tentei, e com require tbm :/ @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: require só mudo o tipo de erro emitido, o `_once` previne adicionar mais de uma vez. Se não é o `include` então pode ser uma função recursiva sua

Comment: Acho que é algum problema com os arquivos incluídos, nestes arquivos eu não ponho cabeçalho nada, já começa com `<p>Título</p>`... vocẽ acha que pode ser tipo uma tag sem fechamento, ou deve ter a ver com o php que estou escapando no HTML... Sabe se tem jeito de acessar um log, sei lá..?

Comment: Gustavo geralmente quando entra em um loop infinito não é gerado log até o processo terminar, os unicos tipos de erros que acredito serem possiveis de capturar são os erro de marcação e do fim de execução. Isto é devido o processo do PHP ocorrer de modo sincronizado e não assincrono. No entanto talvez exista uma estrutura de depuração semelhante aos compiladores de C/C++ como GCC por exemplo, que quando executado em DEBUG seja possivel fazer um "backtrace" e se a aplicação for finalizada prematuramente então você teria o log (no entanto não seria algo fácil de ler). Vou pesquisar

Comment: Ok, valeu! Tava pensando em tentar [debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-backtrace.php), mas nem sei como fazer...

Comment: Gustavo o debug_backtrace é mais para o uso dentro da execução, que pode funcionar, mas terá que uma um método autoload talvez, pois se não o processo será todo manual, antes de você conseguir obter algum resultado relevante.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, instalei o composer, mas não consegui instalar o monolog (hoje tá complicado  pqp :/), mas decidi colocar tudo num arquivo só e encontrei onde estava o erro. Editei a pergunta, dá uma olhada... Valeu, abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme está pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14341757/1518921) existem algumas ferramentas para isto, como:

### [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog)

Instalando com composer:

```
$ composer require monolog/monolog
```

Exemplo básico de uso:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('pasta/seu-arquivo-de-log.log', Logger::WARNING));

// Adiciona gravações para o log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

### [phptrace](https://github.com/Qihoo360/phptrace)

(eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que só funciona com FPM, apache2handler que é mais comum no windows com apache talvez não funcione)

1. Extraia a extensão:

   ```
   tar -zxf phptrace-{version}.tar.gz
   cd phptrace-{version}
   ```
2. Compile a extensão

   ```
   cd extension
   {php_bin_dir}/phpize
   ./configure --with-php-config={php_bin_dir}/php-config
   make
   make install
   ```

   (no caso se for windows e mingw provavelmente terá que usar `mingw32-make`)
3. Copie a extensão compilada para a pasta de extensões do php e edite o php.ini

   ```
   extension=trace.so
   ```
4. Compile o commandtool

   ```
   cd cmdtool
   make
   ```
5. Testando se a instalação está ok:

   ```
   php -r 'for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) usleep(10000);' & ./phptrace -p $!
   ```

Comment: Valeu cara, vou tentar aqui! +1