# Sistema de Log em Sistema de Gerenciamento de Dados

Tags: php, laravel, modelagem

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento de dados em **PHP Laravel 5**.

Nesse sistema quero colocar um Sistema de **Logs**.

1 - O Laravel tem alguma biblioteca que facilita esse sistema ?

2 - Se o Laravel não tiver qual a melhor maneira de fazer um sistema assim ?

3 - Como posso modelar os dados na base ?

Eu pensei no seguinte caso:

Usuário Fulano **(quem)** alterou/criou/deletou/encaminhou **(ação)** chamado ID 43 **(o que)** na data 17/11/2015 **(quando)**.

E pensei em uma tabela simples com as seguintes colunas:

```
ID_LOG
ID_USER
ACAO
DESCRICAO
DATA
```

Talvez a pergunta seja ampla quando uso as expressões 'qual a melhor maneira' ou 'como posso fazer'.

Minha dúvida principal é se o **Laravel** pode me facilitar as coisas.

Comment: Não vem o monolog junto?

Comment: Então, eu não sei usar isso. Mas tem essa pasta na pasta **vendor**. Não sei como é seu uso.

Comment: Pode ser um começo => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72844/91

Comment: A própria pagina do Laravel pode te ajudar http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors

Comment: @TaoPaiPai, teve um sistema que eu fiz isso. Só que eu fiz apenas para "acessos estranhos", ou seja, apenas quando tinha erro 500. Dá pra fazer com os eventos do Model. Por exemplo `saving`, `updating`, que vão identificar que o model teve um evento de salvamento.

Comment: @rray. Mas é possível gravar na base de dados ao invés de um arquivo `.log` usando o **Monolog** ?

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisará para fazer essas operações em Models provavelmente se chama `Model Observers`.

Você pode ver alguns exemplos na página do Laravel.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers

```
class UserObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        //
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        RegistrarLog::create([
            "observacao" => "Alterou um usuário",
            "id" => Auth::user()->id,
            "usuario_alterado_id" => $model->id
        ]);
    }

}

User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

Consequentemente, quando você utilizar o método `save` ou `update`, você fará com que o sistema automaticamente insira os dados do método `UserObserver::saved`.

Ainda outra coisa que pode ser feita é usar o `Model Events`.

Veja elas na página:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

Eles são creating, updating, saving, e deleting. Os nomes já sugerem o que cada um fará em cada ação no model.

Os exemplos demonstrados mostram que esses métodos devem ser definidos no model observado (o que você vai querer registrar um log automaticamente).

Comment: Bacana isso aí, laravel :D

Comment: Nunca usei, kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.

Comment: Se é do laravel deve funcionar :D ele ta ai pra facilitar a vida do pessoal.

Comment: Daqui a pouco vou fazer esse esquema.